# Configure trusted CA for Self-signed JWS application

Tags: java, ssl, code-signing, java-web-start, certificate-authority

1. I have a Self-signed Certificate Authority made with OpenSSL.
2. I used this(1) authority to create a SSL certificate for signing
   JARs.
3. I made a JaveWebStart application and signed it with the certificate (2)
4. I have a client machine with JDK 1.7.0_13 installed. I used the following command to import CA certificate(1) into the JDK:

   ```
   $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias my-root-ca \
   -file root.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts
   ```
5. I launch the app (3) using the JDK (4), but I see that the publisher is UNKNOWN
   [image: Security Warning]
6. If I press "More Information" than I can see my certificate chain, so jar most probably signed properly.

What have I missed? How can I make JWS recognize that my root CA(1) is trusted?